# ¿Cual es la diferencia al declarar mis funciones con let, var y const?

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta es, ¿Puedo usar `let` para declarar funciones?
He visto muchos tutoriales en donde declaran funciones con `conts`, pero a mí me gusta más con `let` si alguien me puede ayudar o dar un consejo lo leeré.

```
let saludar = function (a) {
  return a;
}
console.log("Hola Mundo");
```

Comment: ¿Ayudar con qué? `let` declara variables, `const` declara constantes. De ahí el uso de una forma u otra depende del caso de uso.

Comment: La verdadera pregunta es: ¿para qué usar let si ya está var o el function nombre() {}?

Comment: @TechManWalker principalmente para aprovechar el ámbito de alcance y evitar errores por sobre escritura.

Comment: El var corta automáticamente el alcance; puedes usar el var en el lugar de let.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo por lo que entiendo estás preguntando como llamar a `x` función te explico a lo que yo sé.

Según yo:

`let` te permite guardar variables en un campo local.

`var` te permite guardar variables en un campo global.

`Const` te permite guardar una variable que jamás va a cambiar. Ojo no lo confundas con inmutable.

```
let UserEmail = "tucorreo@tucorreo.com"
const IVA = 16
```

Ahora bien para nombrar una función se hace de la siguiente manera.

```js
function saludar(a){

    console.log("Hola " + a + " Bienvenido a mi pagina." )
    console.log("^- Esto es de la funcion saludar" )

}

saludar("XxTavo16xX")

//Ahora algunos tips

function saludarUser(userName){
  
  if(userName == null){
      // Esto verifica si la variable que le envias si se le haya enviado.
      
      console.log("No existe userName")
      console.log("^- Esto es de la funcion saludarUser, pero como no existe userName muestra Error y hace return" )
      
      return
      
      /*
      
        Tambien puedes hacerlo asi
        
        if(userName == null) return
      
      */
      
  
  }  
  
  
  
  console.log("Hola " + userName + " Bienvenido a mi pagina." )
  console.log("^- Esto es de la funcion saludarUser" )
  

}

saludarUser()

saludarUser("XxTavo16xX")
```

Así es como nombras a una función. Espero te sirva de algo, si aún tienes dudas dime. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Hola, te sugiero repasar [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para entender cuando utilizar uno o el otro, tenemos que entender cuál es la diferencia entre usar `var`, `let` y `const`:

`Var` -> Con `var` el `scope` es su contexto de ejecución o en el caso de una variable declarada fuera de la función el `scope` es `global`.

`Let` -> `Let` introduce el `blockscope` lo cual se refiere a que la variable asignada como `let` solo será accesible dentro del `scope` donde se ha declarado.

`Const` -> `Const` es muy similar a `Let`, pero cuenta con la característica de que no se puede reasignar su valor

Veamos algunos ejemplos con funciones, dijéramos que tenemos nuestra función saludar declarada con `var` de la siguiente forma:

```
var saludar = function (a) {
    return a;
}

console.log(saludar("Hola Mundo"));
```

Funcionaria sin ningún problema, sin embargo si más adelanté nosotros cometiéramos el error de sobreescribirla accidentalmente en algún método diferente o en alguna sección del código que afecte nuestro `global scope` esta dejaría de funcionar correctamente, por ejemplo con algo así:

```
saludar = function(a,b){
    return `Hola me gusta apoyar en ${a} con dudas de ${b}`;
}
console.log(saludar("StackOverflow","Javascript")); 

// ...
// Código más adelante
console.log(saludar("Hola Mundo")); // Hola me gusta apoyar en Hola Mundo con dudas de undefined
```

Si nosotros no quisiéramos tener este riesgo de sobreescribir funciones con nuestro `escope global` en ese caso podríamos utilizar `let` para declarar nuestras funciones y ejecutarlas dentro de nuestro ámbito, lo cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
let saludar = function (a) {
    return a;
}

console.log(saludar("Hola Mundo"));
```

Y ya no se vería afectada de manera externa, sin embargo dentro de nuestro bloque o alcance de nuestra función, sigue existiendo el riesgo de sobreescribir nuestras funciones:

```
// imaginemos que estamos en el mismo bloque de codigo 
saludar = function(a,b){
    return `Hola me gusta apoyar en ${a} con dudas de ${b}`;
}
console.log(saludar("StackOverflow","Javascript"));

console.log(saludar("Hola Mundo")); // Hola me gusta apoyar en Hola Mundo con dudas de undefined
```

Así que la solución para evitar sobreescribir nuestras funciones dentro y fuera del `scope` es declararlas del tipo `const`, lo cual evita que tengamos efectos inesperados:

```
const saludar = function (a) {
    return a;
}

console.log(saludar("Hola Mundo"));
```

Y al intentar sobreescribir nuestra función nos regresará un `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` evitando que modifiquemos nuestras funciones declaradas.

```
saludar = function(a,b){
    return `Hola me gusta apoyar en ${a} con dudas de ${b}`;
}
```

Agrego algunas referencias para entender mas a detalle los usos y alcances de `Var`, `Let` y `Const`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types